# I need help Comparing two list in Java

Tags: java

```
List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

for (Status tweet : tweets) {
    if(!(tweet.getUser().getScreenName().toString().equals("gh") || tweet.getUser().getScreenName().toString().equals("gh"))){
        List<Status> Stats=  tw.getHomeTimeline();        
        for (Status StatList : Stats) {  
            if(->here i want to compare HomeTimelin list of tweets with getTweets list<-){                      
                try {
                    System.out.println(tweet.getUser().getScreenName() );
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } 
                catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }        
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("retweeted");
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("derp blocked");
    }
```

In the second if statement i would like to compare the hometimeline list items and gettweet list , if hometime line list doesnt have the item from gettweet i would like it to return turn, if hometime line has it i would like it to return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
    List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
    List<Status> Stats=  tw.getHomeTimeline();
    for (Status tweet : tweets) {

        if(!(tweet.getUser().getScreenName().toString().equals("gh") || tweet.getUser().getScreenName().toString().equals("gh"))){

            boolean found = false;
            for (Status StatList : Stats) {  

                if(StatList.getTweetText().equals(tweet.getTweetText())){   
                    found = true;
                    break;
                    try {
                        System.out.println(tweet.getUser().getScreenName() );

                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }else{
                    // nothing here
                    // System.out.println("retweeted");
                }
            }
            if (found) // you can move this and the initialisation(boolean found = false) out side the upper if statement
                System.out.println("false");
            else
                System.out.println("turn");

        }else{
            System.out.println("derp blocked");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use retainAll to compare two lists. like below:

```
tweets.retainAll(Stats); // or whatever the names are:
```

Also as a side note: variable names should start from lower case letter always !.